# How to enlarge shadow radius for a view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-drawable, shadow

I have a ImageView that I want to add a shadow to it, but with a large radius area.!

I tried using `elevation` but it doesn't seem to increase the radius very much..!

I also tired using xml drawable shape but with no luck.
 Here's an example of what I want to achieve. assuming the white circle is the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I tried using elevation but it doesn't seem to increase the radius very much..!`

I think the *ImageView* doesn't implement the `elevation` attribute, you can just write attribute because *ImageView* is a subclass from *View* class.

If you need to implement that elevation and got the shadow, do it with `FloatingActionButton` instead or if you don't need to use `FloatingActionButton` and keep going with ImageView you have to set a `CardView` as a container for `ImageView` and add the elevation to `CardView`.

Comment: my bad, I didn't explain enough.. that's what I meant, when i tried to use elevation I wrapped the imageview with linearlayout. but the the problem kinda remains since it only increase the shadow but on small and kinda fixed radius. Fab button is the same thing.

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa If you used FaButton, You just need to put it inside a main container Layout.

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa If my answer helped you, you can mark it as accept, or if you struggle any issue write it>

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by using `CardView` (on Lollipop or higher; pre-Lollipop this won't work):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="24dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_24dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]